# Use 'project' function in {terra} raster package, treat NA as 0s

Tags: raster, terra, rstats

I'm trying to resample/project a high res raster, using a low res raster as a template

```
library("terra")

high_res <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1, NA, NA, NA))

low_res <- rast(nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

new_rast <- project(high_res, low_res, method = "average")
```

This works fine, but the value in the cell of the new rast is '1' as it has taken the average of all non-NA cells from the high_res raster.

Instead, I want it to treat NA values as 0. The result should be 0.25, not 1.

The method to do this must be memory-safe as I will be doing this on very large rasters (think 5m resolution covering a whole country).

Is there a clever way of doing this please?

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75655057/635245

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat `NA`s as 0, use `app()` to do that first, then project:

```
library("terra")

high_res <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1, NA, NA, NA))
high_res0 <- app(high_res, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))

low_res <- rast(nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

new_rast <- project(high_res, low_res, method = "average")
new_rast0 <- project(high_res0, low_res, method = "average")

new_rast
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 360, 180  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source(s)   : memory
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     1 
max value   :     1 

new_rast0
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 360, 180  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source(s)   : memory
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :  0.25 
max value   :  0.25
```